# Using Folder Wildcard

Tags: batch-file, wildcard

I am new to batch scripting and I am trying to write a batch file that will uninstall Yahoo Search Toolbar. Currently the batch will run if the file exists in the Yahoo folder and then run the uninstall command. I within the Yahoo folder there is an hexadecimal folder that changes on every machine. I need to be able to set that folder as a wildcard so my batch will find the file I need to run. Below I have copied what I currently have. I need help with line 16. Any suggestions are welcome!

```
@ECHO OFF
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\AskPartnerNetwork\Toolbar\toolbar.exe" ( 
GOTO COMMAND1
) ELSE (
GOTO COMMAND2
)


:COMMAND1
rem Search App by Ask
  msiexec /quiet /x "{4F524A2D-5350-4500-76A7-A758B70C2E03}"
GOTO COMMAND2


:COMMAND2
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Yahoo!\yset\<WILDARD FOLDER>\ysearchsettool.exe" 
( 
GOTO COMMAND3
) ELSE (
GOTO COMMAND4
)


:COMMAND3
rem Yahoo Search Set
  msiexec /quiet /x "{C57192ED-5069-1A45-845C-C8D5C44F1F40}"
GOTO COMMAND4 


:COMMAND4
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Toolbar\GoogleToolbarUser_32.exe" ( 
GOTO COMMAND5
) ELSE (
GOTO END
)


:COMMAND5
rem Google Toolbar for Internet Explorer
  msiexec /quiet /x "{18455581-E099-4BA8-BC6B-F34B2F06600C}"
GOTO COMMAND6


:COMMAND6
TASKKILL /IM msiexec.exe
GOTO END

:END
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to check whether the toolbars exist?

Would not

```
for %%a in (4F524A2D-5350-4500-76A7-A758B70C2E03
            C57192ED-5069-1A45-845C-C8D5C44F1F40
            18455581-E099-4BA8-BC6B-F34B2F06600C) do msiexec /quiet /x "{%%a}" 2>nul
```

do precisely the same? `msiexec` won't be able to uninstall an application that isn't installed.

Comment: Would it be better to put a `2>NUL` in there? _I'm assuming `msiexec` will complain if it's non existent!_

Comment: Thank you Magoo for the quick response, I get a "This action is only valid for products that are currently installed." I must have the identifying  number wrong.

Comment: As @compo suggested, a `2>nul` will *probably* suppress the error message (if `msiexec` follows the "rule" of sending error messages to `stdout`)